# React useEffect doesn't change data displayed on map

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I'm playing with **uber's** `react-map-gl` and `deck-gl` libraries to try to display data dynamically.I've got 2 components in my react little app.A navigation bar and a `Mapbox map`.So here is my pipeline.When the page first loads,only the map is displayed without any marker or visual data.But when i click on one of navigation bar `link`,an `action creator` gets called,when i make an `ajax` call to fetch some data,and from the action that is dispatched a pass my response data as payload and the `reducer` is reached so that i have a new version of the store.the data that i would like to visualize in they stor key : `mainProjects` that contains an array of `geojson`.My click on a navbar link succefully updates that value,and in the actual `Map` component,i can load the new values but `useEffect` does not update my localstate.Here is my map code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { StaticMap } from "react-map-gl";
import { MapContext } from "./contexts/MapProvider";
import DeckGL, { GeoJsonLayer } from "deck.gl";
import chroma from "chroma-js";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const MAPBOX_TOKEN =
  "pk.mykey";
const mapStyle = "mapbox://mymapstyle";

function getEnergyFillColor(regime) {
  const ENERGY_COLORS = {
    naturalGaz: "#FF8500",
    coal: "#99979A",
    nuclear: "#E0399E",
    hydroelectric: "#0082CB",
    Wind: "#00B53B",
    solar: "#DBCA00",
    oil: "#FF0009",
    other: "#FFEFD3"
  };

  let color;
  switch (regime) {
    case "Hydraulique":
      color = ENERGY_COLORS.hydroelectric;
      break;
    case "Thermique":
      color = ENERGY_COLORS.nuclear;
      break;
    default:
      color = ENERGY_COLORS.other;
      break;
  }
  color = chroma(color)
    .alpha(0.667)
    .rgba();
  color[3] *= 255;
  return color;
}

function _onClick(info) {
  if (info.object) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    alert(
      `${info.object.properties.NOM} (${info.object.properties.PROVINCE}) - ${
        info.object.properties.PUISSANCE
      }MW`
    );
  }
}

function Map({ mainProjects }) {
  const { viewport, setViewport, onLoad } = useContext(MapContext);
  const [airports, setAireports] = useState();
  const [electricalEnergy, setElectricalEnergy] = useState();
  const [hospitals, setHospitals] = useState();
  const [roads, setRoads] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mainProjects.length) {
      setHospitals(mainProjects[0].hospitals);
      setAireports(mainProjects[1].aeroports);
      setElectricalEnergy(mainProjects[2].electricite);
      setRoads(mainProjects[2].routes);
    }
  }, [airports, electricalEnergy, hospitals, roads]);
  const layers = [
    //ENERGIE ELECTRIQUE
    new GeoJsonLayer({
      id: "energy",
      data: electricalEnergy,
      // Styles
      filled: true,
      pointRadiusMinPixels: 20,
      opacity: 1,
      pointRadiusScale: 2000,
      getRadius: energyItem => energyItem.properties.puissance * 3.14,
      getFillColor: energyItem =>
        getEnergyFillColor(energyItem.properties.regime),
      // Interactive props
      pickable: true,
      autoHighlight: true,
      onClick: _onClick
    }),

    //AEROPORTS
    new GeoJsonLayer({
      id: "airports",
      data: airports,
      // Styles
      filled: true,
      pointRadiusMinPixels: 20,
      opacity: 1,
      pointRadiusScale: 2000,
      getRadius: energyItem => energyItem.properties.PUISSANCE * 3.14,
      getFillColor: energyItem =>
        getEnergyFillColor(energyItem.properties.REGIME),
      // Interactive props
      pickable: true,
      autoHighlight: true,
      onClick: _onClick
    }),

    //HOSPITALS
    new GeoJsonLayer({
      id: "hospitals",
      data: hospitals,
      // Styles
      filled: true,
      pointRadiusMinPixels: 20,
      opacity: 1,
      pointRadiusScale: 2000,
      getRadius: energyItem => energyItem.properties.PUISSANCE * 3.14,
      getFillColor: energyItem =>
        getEnergyFillColor(energyItem.properties.REGIME),
      // Interactive props
      pickable: true,
      autoHighlight: true,
      onClick: _onClick
    }),

    //ROUTES
    new GeoJsonLayer({
      id: "roads",
      data: roads,
      pickable: true,
      stroked: false,
      filled: true,
      extruded: true,
      lineWidthScale: 20,
      lineWidthMinPixels: 2,
      getFillColor: [160, 160, 180, 200],
      getLineColor: d => [255, 160, 20, 200],
      // getLineColor: d => colorToRGBArray(d.properties.color),
      getRadius: 100,
      getLineWidth: 1,
      getElevation: 30,
      onHover: ({ object, x, y }) => {
        // const tooltip = object.properties.name || object.properties.station;
        /* Update tooltip
           http://deck.gl/#/documentation/developer-guide/adding-interactivity?section=example-display-a-tooltip-for-hovered-object
        */
      },
      onClick: _onClick
    })
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <link
        href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.0/mapbox-gl.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />
      <DeckGL
        initialViewState={viewport}
        viewState={viewport}
        controller={true}
        layers={layers}
        onLoad={onLoad}
        onViewportChange={nextViewport => setViewport(nextViewport)}
      >
        <StaticMap mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN} mapStyle={mapStyle} />
      </DeckGL>
    </>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = ({
  selectedLinks: { sectorSelected, provinceSelected, subSectorSelected },
  mainProjects
}) => {
  if (sectorSelected || provinceSelected || subSectorSelected) {
    return {
      mainProjects
    };
  } else {
    return {
      mainProjects: []
    };
  }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Map);
```

In the above code,i try to update my local state values by is setters,but `useEffect` doesn't seem to work.And it looks like it's only called once,at when the component renders for the first time.How can i solve this problem?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useEffect has a set of dependencies that donˋt match those, which are actually used.
You are setting your local state with elements of mainProjects, so useEffect will only do something when mainProjects changes.

You donˋt seem to be doing anything with your useState-Variables, so you donˋt change state, so react doesnˋt rerender.

Update: it is really important to check, that the dependency-array (2nd argument to useEffect) and the used variables inside the function (1st argument) correspond, else bad things will happen ;-)

There is an eslint-rule for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks

Comment: How come?I'm calling the setters inside useEffect to update the state.I think it should work

Comment: useEffect takes two parameters: a function to be executed and an array of dependencies. That array may be missing, in which cas useEffect will be called on each render. Or that array may be empty, in which case useEffect will be called just once. Or it contains all the variables that are used in the function, in which case that function will be executed whenever a variable from that array changes. In your case the dependency-array had variables that are not used in the function. Instead you are using props.

Comment: Your answer isn't clear at all.I have this code `useEffect(() => {
    if (mainProjects.length) {
      setHospitals(mainProjects[0].hospitals);
      setAireports(mainProjects[1].aeroports);
      setElectricalEnergy(mainProjects[2].electricite);
      setRoads(mainProjects[2].routes);
    }
  }, [airports, electricalEnergy, hospitals, roads]);` where i'm using the `useEffect` method to update state,but you say that `so useEffect will only do something when mainProjects changes.`

Comment: Ohh,okay i didn't undertand what you said so far,i'm sorry for downvoting.I've changed  `[airports, electricalEnergy, hospitals, roads]` to `[mainProjects]` and now it works.It should watch on the `maintProject prop`

Comment: But i cannot upvote until you make some little change to your initial answer,it locked.So sorry for downvote

Comment: ok, thanx. Added hint to eslnt-rule which helps to avoid these situations.